# maven multi-profile hierarchical dependency issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, development-environment, production-environment

I have a project structure like A.war uses B.jar, B.jar uses C.jar and D.jar, C.jar uses E.jar. All of these war/jar lifecycles are managed by maven. Like everyone, I needed to separate execution environment with "production" and "development" (read from different .properties files) I use a property and called `environment` and set it different values for each profile. It also stands for `classifier` attribute for each war/jar. All of these projects are successfully compiled and exported into appropriate *dev.jar or *-prod.jar. An example configuration for project B is like;

```
<build>
    .....
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${environment}</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/b-${environment}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>prod</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!environment</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <environment>dev</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <!-- C.jar dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.baz.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>c</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <classifier>${environment}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies
```

As a result, I want to use e.g. B-prod.jar in A-prod.war, C-prod.jar in B.prod.jar, so on. Thus far, it seems so good. The root jar (B.jar) can successfully use C.jar and D.jar with its same environment (dev or prod).

**Question**:
When I try to use B.jar as a dependency in A.war, again I can depend B-dev.jar in A-dev.war and B-prod.jar in A-prod.war. However, as the `dev` profile is default one (for all projects), I cannot make a dependency like C-prod.jar from A-prod.war, I always get C-dev.jar within A-prod.war. I think probable issue is when I execute maven-war-plugin, it check for the same `environment` value for B.jar, but it uses default `environment` value (which is `dev`) for the rest of the chain dependencies.

Any suggestions?

**P.S.** There's no `module` relation betweens war and jar(s), and they don't use a common parent pom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by looking at your <classifier>${environment}</classifier> when 'A' is deployed in production, it must pick the production version of 'C' isnt it?

Comment: Absolutely, C.jar is not defined as a dependency in project A's pom, but it's a chain dependency which is defined in project B's pom.

Comment: so even if its a chain dependency, if B is in production it must use C-Prod. I wonder if you change the default environment in property configuerer and see the same result

Comment: B.prod.jar uses C.prod.jar, that's OK, but even C-prod.jar depends on E-prod.jar; when I try to pack them all (within A-prod.war) I can clearly see that E-dev.jar is used by B-prod.jar, as a result A-prod.war uses E-dev.jar. BTW I already use spring property placeholder configurer, to inject required property values, but I don't have any problem about it, I don't override 'environment' property, just use it.